# Writing a makefile for an project with some arranged folders

Tags: linux, makefile

I have the makefile below and a directory tree :

->project/src/main.c, func.c, 
Makefile

->project/exe/

->project/inc/

->project/obj/

```
  cc=gcc
    cflags=-c
    obj=../obj
    exe=../exe
    inc=../inc
    prog.exe: main.o func.o
        $(cc) main.o func.o -o $(exe)/prog.exe
    main.o: main.c $(inc)/defs.h
        $(cc) $(cflags) main.c
        mv main.o $(obj)/
    func.o: func.c $(inc)/defs.h
        $(cc) $(cflags) func.c
        mv func.o $(obj)/
```

The problem is, the second actions below main.o and func.o (those start with mv) doesn't work (i.e main.o isn't moved to the /obj directory). Is there a problem in the syntax of makefile or anything else?

Comment: "doesn't work": Please describe the problem more accurately. Both an Energizer Bunny without batteries and the Challenger spaceship "doesn't work", but in vastly different ways.

Comment: There is a long standing convention of using CC, CFLAGS, etc. (all caps.)  These work with implicit rules so that you do not even need to specify rules in many cases.  It is unwise to flaunt convention by using different names.

Comment: @WilliamPursell
It was just a naive try for practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One apparent problem is that the makefile doesn't build the targets it's supposed to build. I.e.:

```
prog.exe: main.o func.o
    $(cc) main.o func.o -o $(exe)/prog.exe
```

Doesn't build `prog.exe`, rather it builds `$(exe)/prog.exe`, which is a different file. A fix would be:

```
$(exe)/prog.exe: $(obj)/main.o $(obj)/func.o
    $(cc) $^ -o $@
```

Prefer using [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for the names of input and output files to avoid duplication and silly typos.

Comment: yes, but it didn't fix my problem . main.o couldn't be moved.

Comment: No it was for the apparent problem you noticed

Answer (score 0):

You may take care of the indentation with make. It needs real tabs.

See https://superuser.com/questions/224434/what-is-the-character-used-to-indent-the-make-file-rule-recipe

Comment: main.o:<tab>main.c $(inc)/defs.h   
<tab>$(cc) $(cflags) main.c
<tab>mv main.o $(obj)/
still have the problem.